# Utilising jQuery Response From User Entered Form Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how can i take the input from html and then send it to jQuery after that send it to html

this is my code but its does not work :(

my code is taking the input from the user and send it to jQuery after that it return the audio to my index.html

```html
 
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#idbut").click(function() 
{
            
  // Request 
  jQuery.getJSON
  (
    "http://vaas.acapela-group.com/Services/UrlMaker?jsoncallback=?",
    {
      prot_vers: 2, cl_login: "", cl_app: "", cl_pwd: "", 
      req_voice:"leila8k", 
      req_text:$("#demo_voices_textarea").val()
    },
    function(data) 
    {
      //api response management 
      $("#demo1player").html("<audio src='"+data.snd_url+"' controls='controls' />"); 
    }      
  );
});
</script> 
</head>
<body>

  <div id="demo1player" ></div>

 <form>
 <textarea id="demo_voices_textarea"  rows="4" cols="20"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="idbut" value="submit" >
 </form>

</body>
 </html>
```

..... thanks

Comment: Please simplify and clarify your question to better explain the problem.

Comment: What you want to accomplish is not perfectly clear, what type of input do you want from the user? And what type of input (?) do you need to send to html? (??)

Comment: try removing jsoncallback=?  this is handled by jquery on it's own

Comment: Actually, cancel that. I was thinking when you are using the jsonp function.

Comment: yes I need to send to html that display the audio to the user after professed in J query

Comment: The form is trying to submit.  Remove the form tags.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Have you done debugging to see what data, if any, you are getting back in the getJSON response?

Comment: I agree, form could be trying to submit, I would just change the input type to button type="button".

Comment: no there are no  error it just don't return any thing

Comment: Have you verified you are authenticating correctly and that your input variables are correct? You could make a test call with a browser or Fiddler. Also, again, your form is probably submitting so you may want to fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Your form is posting before it can execute your javascript code.

**Try changing this line:**

```
<input type="submit" id="idbut" value="submit" >
```

**To be:**

```
<input type="button" id="idbut" value="submit" >
```

By changing the input type from submit to button, you will prevent the form from submitting and thus get a response from your jQuery code.

Comment: Go ahead and accept this as the answer then please :-) @AfnanM